# How to invoke Method Channel from FCM backend function?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to  call **Bringtoforeground.bringAppToForeground()** plugin when I receive a push notification onBackground but I am getting this error

> ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method bringAppToForeground on channel bringtoforeground)

NOTE - the bringAppToForeground plugin is working fine when I call it from the intState!

This is the background function:

```
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
  if (message.containsKey('data')) {
    final dynamic data = message['data'];
    try {
      print(data);
      //{targetId: Lxz2aYDwlSXOHjLFoQUIb33Y8pP2, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK}
       Bringtoforeground.bringAppToForeground();
    } catch (er) {
      print(er);
      print("Error calling the incoming_call");
    }
  }
}
```

Inside the main function

```
 FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging0 = new FirebaseMessaging();

  _firebaseMessaging0.configure(
    onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isIOS ? null : myBackgroundMessageHandler,
  );
```